# Do high voltage low amperage motors exist?

Tags: motor, charger

I have an idea, which is essentially using the power running down an electrified electric fence to move a stretch of wire between two fences. 
I have been trying to find if it is even possible to have a motor that could run off of the high voltage extremely low amperage output of a typical electric fence.

This would be used to move the wire at a constant rate to automatically move cows for continuous grazing. So it will be necessary to control its travel and have it travel a certain distance for a certain period of time during certain times of the day. So a stepper motor set up might work well?

I am in the very begging process of trying to design this so any help is greatly appreciated. Also, this whole unit will need to be extremely light weight as it will be suspended on a wire, although that might change as well.

Comment: You are definitely not the only person working on this. My opinion is that it would be better to use a small battery powered device. It is hard to get juice from the fence when you are only connected to the hot wire and don't have a connection to the ground wire.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_motor

Comment: "very begging process" is one of the best Freudian slips here, I ever read. SCNR.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is very little **energy** transmitted in an electric fence and it is in the form of short pulses. While the voltage is high (maybe 8 to 10 kV), the current is typically limited to about 100 mA for a few milliseconds and the voltage will rapidly collapse if a load is applied.

You would also be looking for a control circuit that could tolerate 10 kV pulses without being destroyed.

[image]

See [What is electric fencing](https://www.agrisellex.co.uk/pages/what-is-electric-fencing) for some more on the subject.

Comment: would you not be able to capture the pulses in a capacitor and use the capacitor to dampen the peaks and create a relatively more steady flow of power?

Comment: @AndrewWaite: It still amounts to only a few hundred mW of power (average), which wouldn't be enough to do what you want. You can't get more power off the fence than the fence charger itself is putting into it.

Comment: And stealing power from the fence means it can't do its job. Then you have to find a 10 kV capacitor and diodes and prevent someone getting killed.

Comment: IF you were going to do it, I think you would want to use a pulse transformer to get the voltage down to a more manageable level then you could think about rectifiers and capacitors. But, the voltage is highly variable depending on the energizer used and how much loading there is on the fence (for example if wet grass is touching the lowest wire...)

Answer (score 0):

Just run an insulated wire along with the electric fence wire and use conventional power for your motor. You are trying to do too much with too little. What you are attempting is similar to how "center pivot irrigators" work; there is a wire run along the pipe that goes out to a gear motor at the end which is used to drive the irrigator in a circle.

This is moving heavy steel pipes full of water, you would not need that much power to move a wire fence.
[image]